# iOS Bugsnag exception - EXC_BAD_ACCESS _dispatch_dispose Attempted to dereference garbage pointer

Tags: ios, bugsnag

I have an iOS application in production and received the below Bugsnag exception which I am not able to recreate. Can anyone help me to understand what's going on here as the attached stack trace doesn't help me to identify where exactly this is originating.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0xed03a. 
    /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_dispose
    /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib -[OS_dispatch_object _xref_dispose]
    /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib __destroy_helper_block_
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib _Block_release
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation __CFArrayReleaseValues
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation CFRelease
    Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv
    Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv
    Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
    Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:]
    Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation __NSThread__start__
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you had the chance to figure it out the real issue?

Comment: Same issue here..!